# Is there a way for Kafka Connect to ignore 1 field in the schema file and read the other fields into the db

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to sink this schema file into the db, where one of the field type is a map of boolean values

```
reservation table

create table "table-reservation" (
  "sessionId" varchar,
  "enteredReservation" boolean,
  latitude double,
  longitude double
```

schema file

```
{
  "name":"sessionId",
  "type":"string
},
{ 
 "name":"enteredReservation",
 "type": "map",
 "values":"boolean"
},
{
 "name":"latitude",
 "type":"double"
},
{
 "name":"longitude",
 "type":"double"
}
```

config of the sink connector

```
"tasks.max":"1",
"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
"connection.url":"URL",
"topics":"table-reservation",
"quote.sql.identifiers":"always",
"errors.tolerance":"all",
"errors.log.enable":"true",
"errors.log.include.messages":"true"
```

Is there a way to only ignore `enteredReservation` field and set it to null. I read that if we DROP using SMT it can set it to null [DROP SMT](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/drop.html)
However, how would it know which field to drop, while the other stays the same. Or how can the JDBC sink transform a map of boolean values. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: 1. What is a 'topic'? 2. What is a 'field'? These are not SQL terms.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Here the topics are table-reservation and table-session. The fields are the column names in the db schema. This time to avoid the SMT I decided to double quote the table name and field names in the schema to match the schema file. However I do not see the connector showing up and messages reading into the db. Any idea why? I added quote.sql.identifier to double quote it. I initially added SMT to rename the fields for the topics but it is having trouble when I am adding more topics

Comment: @OneCricketeer I updated my post can you please take a look

Comment: The drop SMT nullifies the entire key or value, not fields. I feel like I have said multiple times now that Kafka Streams or KSQL should really be your solution here. SMTs are not meant to be used outside of very simple use cases - https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-nyc17/single-message-transformations-not-transformations-youre-looking/ Or, alternatively, use a document database instead of a flat, relational database table

Comment: @OneCricketeer There is a Kafka Streams in the producer side that produces the messages. However, in the consumer side to reading into the db the log said that "enteredReservation" is a type MAP not boolean which in this case is a map of boolean. Is there a way for the consumer to map it because if I remove in the producer side it can affect the service entirely

Comment: You can write another stream job to flatMap the records until multiple records with a single boolean or, or you can map it and nullify the field. You could also make the same stream job write the data to multiple output topics

Comment: @OneCricketeer I was thinking of the same idea where I flatMap another schema file for the same fields and stream the record into another stream job to flatMap or flatArray into a string or boolean field however no messages came in. Any clue why. Because I checked the logs in the producer side and I see messages produced. but not into the db

Comment: My only suggestion would be check the logs of the consumer, not the database itself

Comment: @OneCricketeer I was thinking of the same way where I checked the logs of the pod and connector but there were no errors showing. Instead it showed INFO that the connector is created and its there and offset is given with partition.  I created a separate schema where it flattens the field and a stream that converts the array Not sure why its not consuming but I see the produced field Any idea Should I add the info to the post and maybe can get an idea

Comment: If there's no error logs, check the connector /status endpoint

Comment: @OneCricketeer So currently in the producer, I have 2 schema files where one is the original schema with the array fields, while the other schema file have the same fields but its flatten where the array field types is instead ["string", "null"]. The kafka producer have 2 parts and 2 streams where it will produce to original schema and another producer to produce it to the flatten topic. Is it possible to have the consumer read from the original producer to the 2nd produce flatten topic. I checked the status and log, said running and successfully joined group with generation170, settin offset

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but `topics` configuration in Connect can read from multiples topics, yes. However, mentioned before that the JDBC sink will fail to write array fields

Answer (score 0):

Below configuration ignores a field you want:

> "transforms": "mask",
>
> "transforms.mask.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.MaskField$Value",
>
> "transforms.mask.fields": "enteredReservation "

But it may not work for types other than string and numerical ones. So, you can also try blacklisting:

> "transforms": "ReplaceField",
>
> "transforms.ReplaceField.type":
> "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
>
> "transforms.ReplaceField.blacklist": "enteredReservation "